# Printing origin servers name in Apache log

Tags: apache-2.2, http, reverse-proxy, http-headers

I have configured a reverse proxy setup with Apache as the reverse proxy server and JBoss nodes as origin servers.

How do i get the name of origin servers logged in to Apache log. I don't see any format strings related to this in [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) or in the standard [apache custom log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

Should i print the hostname of the origin server in HTTP header of jboss and then use the header in Apache with `%{header}o` format string ?

Comment: Are JBoss nodes clustered or they serve different content? Have you tried with a dedicated AJP protocol instead of classic HTTP to connect proxy to nodes?

Comment: JBoss nodes are not clustered. But they serve the same application. Due to legacy reason HTTP is used instead of AJP.

Comment: I think your best bet is to implement the idea you presented. If you want an actual server name (as opposed to an IP) then have JBoss return it as an HTTP header, and capture it in the apache log. You might also be able to use apache to strip it from the HTTP response so the client won't have to download the extra bytes, and you won't be exposing more information to clients than you need to. We do something very similar with IIS and a commercial load balancer, but kind of in reverse, having the load balancer inject HTTP headers which the web servers then write to their individual web logs.